# Changing icon on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on icon change on click and hover with angularJS. My problem is that suppose if my default value is "1" and I click on it, then the result will be "2" and vice-versa and  If I hover on any "1" or "2" my result should be "3" and on removing the pointer off the number it reverts back to its original value, whichever was there on hover. 
Here is my code on which I am working on along with the snippet..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .red > #icon_span2{
                display:block;
            }
            .red > #icon_span1{
                display:none;
            }
            .red > #icon_span12{
                display:none;
            }
            .blue > #icon_span1{
                display:block;
            }
            .blue > #icon_span2{
                display:none;
            }
            .blue > #icon_span12{
                display:none;
            }
            .grey > #icon_span12{
                display:block;
            }
            .grey > #icon_span1{
                display:none;
            }
            .grey > #icon_span2{
                display:none;
            }
            #icon_span1 {
                display:none;
            }
            #icon_span2{
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
        <div>
            <a ng-class="class" ng-click="changeClass()" ng-mouseenter="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
                <span  id="icon_span2">
                    1
                </span>
                <span id="icon_span1">
                    2
                </span>
                <span id="icon_span12" >
                    3
                </span>
                <span class="text"> Feed</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("ap",[]);
    app.controller("con",function($scope){
        $scope.class = "blue";
        $scope.changeClass = function(){
            if ($scope.class === "red")
                $scope.class = "blue";
            else
                $scope.class = "red";
        };
        var mal=$scope.class;
        $scope.hoverIn=function(){
            $scope.class="grey";
        }
        $scope.hoverOut=function(){
            if ($scope.class === "grey")
                $scope.class = "blue";
            else if
                ($scope.class === "blue")
                $scope.class = "red";
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where is the problem? the code snippet works. Or do you want a different behavior?

Comment: the problem is if i hover out  the value it should restore to the original value..
for e.g: if i hover on "1" it should be "3" and when i hover out the value should again be "1". This works well, no doubt. But the problem is with the value "2". have a close look... Value "2" does not restore to its original value after hover out. There is a problem with the hoverOut()

Comment: don't use class as variable on your scope and as class name. try adding a prefix or suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restore the old value, then you need to cache it inside of the controller.

Your code has to look like this (i also changed the if, else block to a ternary):

```
app.controller("con", function ($scope) {
    var classCache; //add a cache variable
    $scope.class = "blue";
    classCache = $scope.class; //set the default value

    $scope.changeClass = function () {
        classCache = $scope.class === "red" ? "blue" : "red"; //remeber the selected class
        $scope.class = classCache;
    };

    $scope.hoverIn = function () {
        $scope.class = "grey";
    };

    $scope.hoverOut = function () {
        $scope.class = classCache; //restore from cache
    }


});
```